# creating different data in a for loop from a data frame of data frame

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have a data frame (called datasTX) of data frames:

I'm not sure how to even reproduce that (the datasTX), but within datasTX, the data-frames are built like this:

```
data <- as.data.frame(seq(as.Date('2017/04/01'), as.Date('2018/11/01'), by="day"))
data <- rlang::set_names(data, "Date")
data[, "Year"] <- format(data[,"Date"], "%Y")
data[, "Month"] <- format(data[,"Date"], "%m")
data[, "Quantity"] <- sample(100, size = nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
```

Now, I'm trying to make a for loop, where for each data in datasTX, it groups by year and month, add up the quantity column per for the year/month.

This is my attempt:

```
for(i in 1:length(datasTX)){
 if (nrow(datasTX[[i]])>=83){  
   monthly <- dplyr::group_by(datasTX[[i]], datasTX[[i]][["Year"]], datasTX[[i]][["Month"]])
   monthly <- dplyr::summarise(monthly, sum(datasTX[[i]][[4]]))
   monthly <- rlang::set_names(monthly, c("Year", "Month", "Quantity"))
 } else {
   print(c("Not enough orders for the item with", nrow(datasTX[[i]]), "rows."))
 }
}
```

(Note: For now, we can ignore the if else statement, basically every data set in datasTX has a different number of rows ranging from 5 to 5,000)

What this code does is just sums up all the quantity values in data. 
What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I really need to understand this for loop. It seems like the line where things go wrong is 
```
   monthly <- dplyr::summarise(monthly, sum(datasTX[[i]][[4]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that automatically by using a pipe with dplyr, grouping the data and then summarizing it.

#### In case of one data-frame

```
library(dplyr)

Date = seq(as.Date('2017/04/01'), as.Date('2018/11/01'), by="day")

data <- 
  data.frame(
    Date,
    Year = format(Date, "%Y"),
    Month = format(Date, "%m"),
    Quantity = sample(100, size = length(Date), replace = TRUE))

data %>%
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%
  summarise(monthly = sum(Quantity))

# # A tibble: 20 x 3
# # Groups:   Year [2]
# Year  Month monthly
# <fct> <fct>   <int>
#   2017  04       1431
#   2017  05       1511
#   2017  06       1819
#   2017  07       1242
#   2017  08       1583
#   2017  09       1385
#   2017  10       1269
#   2017  11       1572
#   2017  12       1132
```

#### In case of list of dataframes

Here you can use purrr (map function equivalent to looping) and give it the same steps that we have done, each loop in map returns a dataframe and then the output is concatenated and the result becomes a list of dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

Date = seq(as.Date('2017/04/01'), as.Date('2018/11/01'), by="day")

data <- 
  data.frame(
    Date,
    Year = format(Date, "%Y"),
    Month = format(Date, "%m"),
    Quantity = sample(100, size = length(Date), replace = TRUE))

datasTX <- list(data, data, data)

1:length(datasTX) %>%
  map(function(x){
    datasTX[[x]] %>%
      group_by(Year, Month) %>%
      summarise(monthly = sum(Quantity))
    })
```

Comment: Yes I know I can do that one data frame at a time, but I have over 500 data sets sitting in a list that I need to do this in. So I think a loop would be better. Unless there is a different way?

Comment: In which format do you want your output to be? list of dataframes?

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm new to r anyway, so I'm not even aware of options? A list of dataframes seems natural, so I would say Yes?

Comment: Yes. You can have it as list of dataframes or you might want to append all dataframes into a single one. I have edited the post now you can do that and the output would be a list of dataframe if you wish to make it a single dataframe instead of using map you will just replace it by map_df.

Comment: if I want to include a name for each data frame (currently named them 1,2,3, etc) do I include names(datasTX) in the function?

Comment: No, If your result will be stored in "my_result" then after storing it in my_result you can rename its contents as follows; names(my_result) <- c(1, 2, 3)

Comment: By after storing I means after the function is over. If your original dataset datasTX has names for each dataframe in list and you wanna reuse those names you can do something like that: names(my_result) <- names(datasTX)